# default environment "maas" does not exist

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I have all my nodes in MAAS UI in ready state, but whenever i try `juju quickstart`
it gives me this error `error: cannot parse "/home/maas-controller/.juju/environments.yaml": default environment "maas" does not exist`

Here's my environments.yaml file

```
default: maas
environments:
maas:
 type: maas
 maas-server: 'http://192.168.119.120/MAAS'
 maas-oauth: <maas-oauth>
 admin-secret: 'nothing'
 default-series: trusty
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't know Juju is so sensitive about indentation. The mistake was, I didn't add a space in third line before

`maas:`

If anyone getting the same error, this or similar might be the cause.

P.S you have to add a space in the lines below also. Updated looks like this:

```
default: maas
environments:
 maas:
  type: maas
  maas-server: 'http://192.168.119.120/MAAS'
  maas-oauth: <maas-oauth>
  admin-secret: 'nothing'
  default-series: trusty
```

Comment: it isn't Juju being picky per se, the environments.yaml file needs to adhere to the YAML spec though (http://yaml.org/spec/)

Comment: Thanks Nick for the info, I am new to Juju that's why i thought so.